# AppleMusicKit library for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, apple-musickit

I am developing an android application form AppleMusicKit. I have fetched user playlist and albums using api's. But now i am trying to play a song using code

```
val tokenProvider = object : TokenProvider {
                override fun getDeveloperToken(): String = token.developerToken
                override fun getUserToken(): String = token.userToken
            }
            val applePlayerController = MediaPlayerControllerFactory.createLocalController(applicationContext, tokenProvider)
            val queueProviderBuilder = CatalogPlaybackQueueItemProvider.Builder()
            queueProviderBuilder.containers(MediaContainerType.PLAYLIST, id)
```

When i **createLocalController** application crashes. This is exception that i got

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.apple.android.music.foothill.javanative.FootHillConfig.config(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_apple_android_music_foothill_javanative_FootHillConfig_config and Java_com_apple_android_music_foothill_javanative_FootHillConfig_config__Ljava_lang_String_2)
                                                                                                        at com.apple.android.music.foothill.javanative.FootHillConfig.config(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.apple.android.music.playback.c.g.a(MusicSDK:23)
                                                                                                        at com.apple.android.music.playback.c.b.<init>(MusicSDK:182)
                                                                                                        at com.apple.android.music.playback.c.f.a(MusicSDK:48)
                                                                                                        at com.apple.android.music.playback.controller.a.<init>(MusicSDK:159)
                                                                                                        at com.apple.android.music.playback.controller.MediaPlayerControllerFactory.createLocalController(MusicSDK:62)
```

I have no idea what i am missing here. I have added FOREGROUND_SERVICE in permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by adding these lines

```
static {

        try {
            // Adding these two lines will prevent the OOM false alarm
            System.setProperty("org.bytedeco.javacpp.maxphysicalbytes", "0");
            System.setProperty("org.bytedeco.javacpp.maxbytes", "0");

            System.loadLibrary("c++_shared");
            System.loadLibrary("appleMusicSDK");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not load library due to: " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            throw e;
        }
    }
```